# Calculation of collector current

Tags: transistors

[image: cicuit]

I know Collector current formulae ic=(vcc- vce)/ R. 
In above circuit 
vcc = 5v
vce= 0.25v(from datasheet).
how can i decide value of R(load).

Answer (score 1):

In the same datasheet you have Ic=10 mA for vce=0.25v
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can assume the transistor is well saturated for a load less than about Ib/20. Since Ib ~= (5V - 0.7V)/21K ~= 0.2mA, ignoring the 100K, you get about 4mA. That's a fairly safe load, despite the Ic/Ib = 10 specification in the datasheet. So if you keep the load 1.25K or greater, you'll be fine. Probably 1K is okay too, at least if you don't need to worry about low temperatures where the gain drops.

If you want to know what will **typically** happen, you can refer to this diagram from a [datasheet](http://www.mccsemi.com/up_pdf/2N3906(TO-92).pdf):

[image]

If you allow a Vce of 1V (so your load would nominally see only 4V), then **typically** a base current of 0.2mA would support a load of about 30-35mA. That's more like 150\$\Omega\$. This is not guaranteed, so you shouldn't design to it. It could be lower or higher than that number, and it will change from unit-to-unit and with temperature.